# SQL Server geometry distance in miles calculation?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, geometry, distance, spatial

- System: SQL Server 2008 R2
- Two geometry variables, SRID 4326.

The return value from `STDistance` is in degrees, but I need miles. Also, imagine doing this kind of calculation not on 2 variables, but on geometry columns in a table with 1000's of rows. What are the fastest solutions? Is there anything built-in to SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016, ...?

```
--Geometry
DECLARE @Point2m geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-80.23 26.2)', 4326),
@Point3m geometry = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(-80.229999999515712 26.193699999712408)', 4326)

SELECT @Point2m.STDistance(@Point3m) /* degrees */
GO

--Geography, for comparison
DECLARE @Point2g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-80.23 26.2)', 4326),
@Point3g geography = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-80.229999999515712 26.193699999712408)', 4326)

SELECT @Point2g.STDistance(@Point3g) / 1609.344 /*meters to miles*/
GO
```

Comment: So what is the question? Did you try it on 1000's of rows and it did not work, it is slow or what?

Comment: Need distance in miles not degrees for geometry type.

Comment: Check this answer out -- should help:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4844/stdistance-unit-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1):

This can be used as a template for an SP:

DECLARE @geostart GEOGRAPHY
DECLARE @geoend GEOGRAPHY

SELECT @geostart = 
SELECT @geoend =

SELECT CAST(@geostart.STDistance(@geoend)/1609.344 AS DEC (8,1)) AS [Distance in Miles]

If you want to calculate the distance in miles for a number of rows (table_a) to a specific geography value (key column value = 100) in another table (table_b) you could use something like this:

SELECT 
    ,'miles'= CAST(table_a_geo.STDistance(table_b_geo)/1609.344 AS DEC (8,1))
FROM table_a
JOIN table_b ON table_b_id = 100